# Add event at Google Calendar to someone unknown calendar

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I have event at my Google Calendar, it is new year eve event. I want to share my event to my co-worker so my co-worker can click that link and automatically add event to their calendar. However, I don't know what calendar or platform their used, I just want to share link to my WhatsApp group. How to do this at my Google Calendar? Please let me know.

I have read some article [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en) about sharing one calendar. I think isn't suitable for me because I share a whole calendar. I just want to share one event. How to do this? anyone who experience?

Comment: You have the option to e-mail the details of an event when you click on it, which allows the recipient to add it to his or her own calendar. Alternatively, you can create a calendar for this single event and share it.

Comment: I dont want to share a whole calendar. I just want to link like `mailto:myemail.com`. Is doesn't care what mail services you use it, but it always send to myemail.com